# Find and filter both not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to find a span with a particular class, which includes a variable to assign it a width attribute in jQuery. I think I can use find() because it is a child element of a td that I am using to find it.

I've tried both find() and filter() and it isn't returning anything.
Help!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //these two variables come from lists
  var person = "Rick";
  var var1 = 2;
  var element = $('td').filter(function() {
    var Text = $(this).contents()[0].textContent.trim();
    return parseInt(Text, 10) == var1;
  });
  add_html = element.append('</br><span class="calendar_element ' + person + '"></span>');
  $(window).on('resize', function() {
    //calculate needed width of span (var for simplicity) 
    var length = 3;
    var cell_width = element.width();

    var width = function() {
      return length * cell_width;
    }
    //why is this not working???
    var resize_span = element.find('.calendar_element ' + person);

    $('span.calendar_element ' + person).css('width', width);
  }).resize();
});
```

```css
div.class1 {
  position: relative;
}

table {
  border: 1px solid navy;
  width: 70%;
  text-align: center;
}

table th {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
}

table td {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: right;
  border: 1px solid #c6c6ec;
}

span.calendar_element {
  background-color: purple;
  height: 14px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class1">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>12</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: The .calendar_element is appended in the javascript with .append() to the td element @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: If I use an exists() function it returns false so it isn't finding the span element @AmericanSlime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has two issues. Firstly, you're defining `width` as a function, so passing it as a value to the `css()` setter won't have the effect you expect. Secondly, your selector is not quite right. You need a `.` prefix on the class selector, and no space between the values as both classes are on the same element. Try this version, with some additional logic amendments:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var person = "Rick";
  var var1 = 2;
  var $element = $('td').filter(function() {
    return parseInt($(this).text().trim(), 10) == var1;
  }).append('<br /><span class="calendar_element ' + person + '"></span>');
  
  $(window).on('resize', function() {
    var length = 3;
    var width = $element.width() * length;    
    $element.find('.calendar_element.' + person).css('width', width);
  }).resize();
});
```

```css
div.class1 {
  position: relative;
}

table {
  border: 1px solid navy;
  width: 70%;
  text-align: center;
}

table th {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
}

table td {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: right;
  border: 1px solid #c6c6ec;
}

span.calendar_element {
  background-color: purple;
  height: 14px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class1">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>12</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm almost there I can't get the css to change once I resize the page though even though it finds the element just fine. What's the reason for the $ on the element? this is just a variable?
And is there a reason to append with the element filter rather than do it later? @Rory McCrossan

Comment: The `$` prefix on a variable is a naming convention to show it holds a jQuery object.

Comment: Ah okay. the only bit that isn't working for me is the .css()

Comment: Also, the issue with resize is because every time it fires you multiply the width of the `span` by `3`, hence it grows exponentially. It's more easy to see in a fiddle as you can resize the output pane without having to change the window: https://jsfiddle.net/hfeq80r2/

Comment: If I print the value of the new width each time the values look okay. Everything looks good, just when I resize the page the css/html doesn't change when I look in chrome developer tools. so .css() isn't working for me

Comment: If I log .width of the element after to the console, it seems the css width is changing. I just can't see any change on the page....